# FlatList is not populating with the request

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to popular a FlatList through a request, however the list is getting empty. I've tried several ways and I can not fill FlatList. Can someone help me?

[image]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, FlatList} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
super();
this.state = {
  listaTarefas: ''
}
fetch('https://b7web.com.br/todo/25088')
.then((r)=> r.json())
  .then((json)=>{
    let state = this.state;
    state.listaTarefas = json.todo;
    this.setState(state);
  })
}

render() {
return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data = {this.state.listaTarefas}
      renderItem = {({item}) => {
        <View>
          <Text>Id: {item.id}</Text>
          <Text>Item: {item.item}</Text>
          <Text>Item: {item.done}</Text>
        </View>
      }}
      keyExtractor = {(item, index) => item.id}
    />
  </View>
);
 }
}
```

Comment: JSON{ todo: [ { id: "7317", item: "Item 1", done: "0" }, { id: "7318", item: "Item 2", done: "0" }, { id: "7319", item: "Item 3", done: "0" }, { id: "7323", item: "Comprar pizza", done: "0" }, { id: "7324", item: "Fazer trabalho", done: "0" } ] }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a small bracket, not a square bracket.

And it is better to separate them so that they are legible.

```js
 _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <View>
          <Text>Id: {item.id}</Text>
          <Text>Item: {item.item}</Text>
          <Text>Item: {item.done}</Text>
        </View>
  );

...
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <FlatList
      data = {this.state.listaTarefas}
      renderItem={this._renderItem}
      keyExtractor = {(item, index) => item.id}
    />
  </View>
);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo

```
renderItem = {({item}) => ( // {
  <View>
    <Text>Id: {item.id}</Text>
    <Text>Item: {item.item}</Text>
    <Text>Item: {item.done}</Text>
  </View>
)} // }}
```